# what is wrong with my java code, as it keeps answering with the default answer?

Tags: java

Does anyone know why when i run this java application, it keeps coming up with the default value, and not the correct answer?

The main code is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClass {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanString = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Calculator");
    System.out.println("Enter 1st number:");
    int x = scanInt.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter opperation:");
    String op = scanString.nextLine();
    System.out.println(op);

    System.out.println("Enter 2nd number:");
    int y = scanInt.nextInt();

    String ans = "The answer is: ";

    if(op == "+"){
        System.out.println(ans + methods.addition(x, y));
    }else if(op == "-"){
        System.out.println(ans + methods.subtraction(x, y));
    }else if(op == "*"){
        System.out.println(ans + methods.multiplication(x, y));
    }else if(op == "/"){
        System.out.println(ans + methods.division(x, y));
    }else{
        System.out.println("UNKNOWN OPPORATOR");
    }
}
}
```

The methods class is below:

```
public class methods {
public static int subtraction(int x, int y){
    return x - y;
}
public static int addition(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}
public static int multiplication(int x, int y){
    return x * y;
}
public static int division(int x, int y){
    return x / y;
}
}
```

Comment: Well, I am reminded of the definition of insanity ...

Comment: You better use one Scanner though.

Comment: By "default answer", do you mean: System.out.println("UNKNOWN OPPORATOR"); ?

Comment: BTW have you checked what "op" evaluates to? e.g. System.out.println("_" + op + "_");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot compare string values with the `==` operator.  The `==` operator compares two object references to determine if they refer to the same object.

To compare string values, use `String#equals`:

```
if("+".equals(op){
```

and likewise for the other comparisons.

Comment: More precisely, you CAN compare instances of java.lang.String with the `==` operator, but only if they have been interned.

Comment: Even more precisely, you can *always* compare instances of java.lang.String with the `==` operator, but it may not do what you actually want it to do. :)